# No value display when listView get clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, position

**Table WorkDetails**

[image]

Load into listView by given  condition `$sql = "select * from work_details WHERE twd= '". $id."'";`  // Assume $id is equal to 1.

[image]

When `listView` get clicked, it suppose to display its id. But no value displayed.

```
    listViewUpdate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            mClickedPosition = position;
            HashMap<String, String> clickedItem = EditDetails.get(position);
            iD=clickedItem.get(Config.TAG_ID);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),iD,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), iD + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to `Log` the value of `iD` and tell what value it has.

Comment: @ParagKadam `Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 19500
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

Comment: try this `Log.e("Value of iD:", iD.toString());` and show the output

Comment: @helldawg13 same error, log not displaying

Comment: Also do this : `Log.e("Value of clickedItem object:", clickedItem.toString())` .

Comment: show the code for EditDetails

Comment: @helldawg13 I have posted at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564100/no-data-retrieved-from-mysql-to-android-listview-by-given-id)

Comment: @ParagKadam Finally it displayed `01-02 18:09:55.693  24319-24319/com.example.project.myapplication E/Value of clickedItem﹕ {id=1, project=   Pro-XXX-XXX, timeOut=00:00:00, percentage=0, timeIn=00:00:00, work_description=  dd}
01-02 18:09:56.713  24319-24319/com.example.project.myapplication E/Value of clickedItem﹕ {id=2, project=   Pro-XXX-XXX, timeOut=00:00:00, percentage=0, timeIn=00:00:00, work_description=  ww}`

Comment: @helldawg13 It solved

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL Query to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM work_details WHERE twd='$id'";
```